# Vagrant: can't get NFS working

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, nfs, vagrantfile

I'm trying to change my VagrantFile so that it uses an NFS mount instead of the default VirtualBox shared folders.

I get this error message:

```
vm:
* Shared folders that have NFS enabled do not support owner/group
attributes. Host path: .
```

This is my VagrantFile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config| 
  config.vm.box = "ktbartholomew/lamp"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
end
```

I can't see any owner or group getting set.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using something other than '.' for the source folder to mount from host?  It seems like that might be your problem.  try defining it with a full path.  Like '/home/user/project' or what ever your path is.  The rest of your statement looks just like what I currently use.

Comment: I just changed it and unfortunately same problem, although now the error message is "* Shared folders that have NFS enabled do not support owner/group
attributes. Host path: /Users/jamesplayer/Sites/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant only raises this error when the owner or group is true. Try forcing it by passing nil for both these options for both synced_folder configs.

`, group: nil, owner: nil`

Here's the code:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/8655d212c327d363f8e80185705ff70bb2e97f6b/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb#L572

Comment: Thanks! This is what my final VagrantFile ended up looking like: VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ktbartholomew/lamp"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.13"
  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/jamesplayer/Sites/", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", group: nil, owner: nil
end

Comment: Basically do not use group, owner, mount_options as attributes

Comment: Vagrant only raises this error when the owner or group _is_ true (and nfs is set)

Comment: Thanks Lotus, fixed the wording.

Answer (score 3):

I've found mapping the uid/gid directly works OK. It's a little weird on the vagrant side, because they are arbitrary users/groups but apart from that it is fine.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...
  config.nfs.map_uid = Process.uid
  config.nfs.map_gid = Process.gid
  config.vm.synced_folder ".",  "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", :nfs => true
  config.vm.synced_folder "..", "/var/www", id: "application",  :nfs => true
end
```