# How to use nfs for vagrant sync specific folders?

Tags: vagrant, synchronization, ubuntu-14.04, nfs

- HOST machine: OS X Mavericks
- GUEST machine: Ubuntu 14.04
- VM software: VirtualBox 4.3.14

Inside my Vagrantfile, I have the following and it is working fine:

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/WebApps", "/var/virtual/WebApps", id: "vagrant-root", 
    owner: "www-data",
    group: "www-data",
    mount_options: ["dmode=755,fmode=755"]
```

I read about [NFS](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) and how it improves performance.

Do I simply just add a `type: nfs` at the end to activate the use of nfs?

Comment: Have you tried it.  As you're on OS X it should just work. You will need root at somepoint during vagrant up but check. https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html

Comment: Got it to work. Weirdly enough, I need not set mount options, owner, or group. My nginx still can write files into the mounted folder. Weird.

Comment: Check /etc/exports and see how vagrant built the mount. Maybe it is doing something like map all to your user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

The most important thing is NOT to have group, owner, and mount_options

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/WebApps", "/var/virtual/WebApps", id: "vagrant-root", 
    type: "nfs"
```

When I attempted to use those attributes, I get failure warnings.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25826201/80353) helped a tad.